# CSS Border Image not working on the IPAD

Tags: css, image, ipad, border

We've tested our border images on all the browsers and they work fine, but they show up as a black border on the IPAD. Tried different images. Tried repeat. Tried stretch. Nothing. Edited   the head with new meta content (as recommended elsewhere) and got an error message. Any ideas?

Thanks...

Part of the CSS:

```
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 14px 14px 14px 14px;
 -moz-border-image: url('..Images/vector.jpg') 25 stretch;
 -webkit-border-image: url('..Images/vector.jpg') 25 stretch;
 -o-border-image: url('..Images/vector.jpg') 25 stretch;
 border-image: url('..Images/vector.jpg') 25 stretch;
```

Comment: what format are the images? how does the CSS look like?

Comment: We are using jpg. Might this be the problem? The image is part of a popup.

Comment: Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ARpkk/ It's possible that the browser on your iPad doesn't support the property (which I can't test). You could add `border-color` and see what happens: http://jsfiddle.net/ARpkk/1/

Comment: Jared: We've even tested with CSS gradients, and it works fine. It's just the border image. New IPAD mini, would be surprised if it didn't support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours tracking this problem down. Ipad is buggy with border-image. More than just this issue.

So, here it is. It has to do with the size of the image. If you use anything over 2000px, it just does not work, 2000 or under does work. My original image was 2300 and it did not, I reduced it to 2000 and it worked.

Now, if I could only figure out the artifacts that are left behind.....